# Import module from directory one level up when running script in subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

Say I have a collection of scripts organized for convenience in a directory structure like so:

```
root
│   helpers.py
│
├───dir_a
│       data.txt
│       foo.py
│
└───dir_b
        data.txt
        bar.py
```

`foo.py` and `bar.py` are scripts doing different things, but they both load their distinct `data.txt` the same way. To avoid repeating myself, I wish to put a `load_data()` function in `helpers.py` that can be imported while running scripts in subdirectories `dir_a` and `dir_b`.

I have tried to import helpers in **`dir_a/foo.py`** using a relative import like this:

```
from ..helpers import load_data

foo_data = load_data('data.txt')

# ...rest of code...
```

But directly running **`foo.py`** as a script fails on line 1 with an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..helpers import load_data
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is the spirit of what I'm attempting possible in python (i.e. simple and without modifying `sys.path`)? From *Case 3: Importing from Parent Directory* [on this site](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html), the answer seems to be no, and I need to restructure my collection of scripts to avoid importing one level up.

Bonus question: if not possible, what is the rationale for why not?

Answer (score 1):

If you create an empty `__init__.py` in the root directory (which turns root into a package) and then call your `foo.py` script like this:

`python -m root.dir_a.foo`

it should work, I think, **so long as you call it from above 'root'**. I've just tried something similar on my machine and it worked.

Alternatively, because you have now made 'root' a package, you can just:

`from root import helpers`

Of course, I assume your root directory isn't really called 'root', in which case you should change it appropriately. I'm also assuming you're using Python3 - it won't work in 2.7.

As to the rationale of why this isn't possible without making root a package, I think the idea is that your code should be location agnostic. In other words, you shouldn't rely on your foo.py knowing where it is on the system. I'm not an expert, but actually it maybe that foo.py *doesn't* know this, in which case it has no way of resolving `../helpers`.

Comment: yes, python 3, i will edit the question to reflect that. might need to puzzle this answer out given my root directory name has hyphens in it. thank you, will test!

Comment: `python -m root.dir_a.foo` does indeed work running one up from root, however the script also lost the location of `data.txt` since it is no longer running in foo. This is not an argument against your much appreciated answer, but I'm curious why foo.py is trusted to know where it is on the system for files in its directory and downward, but not for imports upward. I can only suppose there is a lot more danger in searching for things up the directory tree than down.

Comment: Yeah good question, and you might be right. Searching up might be dangerous? If you need to be able to call it from the current directory, you can add the 'root' directory to your PYTHONPATH, or if you're in a conda environment, you can use 'conda develop'.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to run a python script is from the parent directory of the root package as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65132184/281545) by @JoeTodd. If you run the script directly from its location then it has no way of knowing it is in a package hence the error (no known parent package).

Now as to the data.txt, python when given a relative path it has to resolve it to an absolute path - it can't open 'data.txt' it needs to open c:/path/to/data.txt. Relative paths are therefore concatenated to the current working directory which is by default the directory the script is run from (which is also added to the sys.path and hence the packages inside it are resolved). So when you run from the parent dir of root, python looks for `c:/.../parent dir of root/data.txt` which doesn't exist. The correct solution is to *not* use relative paths - so:

```
path_to_data = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.txt'))
foo_data = load_data(path_to_data)
```

Comment: +1 for `__file__` reference. I did understand where python was looking for foo's data.txt but was hoping for an easy way to keep the easy of code of "look, data.txt is right next to you". this is a low effort fix, if not super convenient to rerun in vscode

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the top of your foo.py script,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../root')
```

Which will set the path to a module a level higher.
You will then be able to do  your import in the foo.py script as follows,

```
from helpers import load_data
```

I was stuck on a very similar issue and found that this is the simplest way of resolving this issue